# Spectral gap (barrier) under centain symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, conformal-field-theory

I have recently been taught the problem of preparing the ground state with an adiabatic process, which requires the instantaneous Hamiltonian to have an energy gap between the ground and the first excited state along the adiabatic path. However, this condition generically does not hold as the problem is known to be QMA-hard.

There is this interesting paper proposed by [Nagaj et al.](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.109.050501) that they apply the property that there is an energy barrier between the first and second excited states that helps to get to the ground configuration (in the case of quantum annealing). At the end of the paper, they mentioned that

> ``the third eigenvalue is always at a distance 1/poly(n) from the two lowest ones. This is a common property for systems that have conformal invariance.''

To my knowledge, the conformal invariance includes space translational invariance. So, is this a common feature for quantum systems that we encountered, especially quantum spin systems including TFIM?